# CoreData with RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mapping, restkit

Try to implement usage of CoreData with RestKit.

**Problem** - got message  `I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'ItemRK' by attributes 'itemID'` and crash. Try to add Exception on errors- cant catch it.

Check mapping - OK;
Check DBModel - OK; empty DB created successfully

I cant understand what was done wrong and where, so I put here main parts of code (sorry for long explanation).

**What was done:**

I try to organize my code like proposed [here](http://restkit-tutorials.com/code-organization-in-restkit-based-app/).

So i create `RKBaseObjectManager` for using RestKit

```
@implementation RKBaseObjectManager

#pragma mark - Public

+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    RKBaseObjectManager *sharedManager = [self managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kBaseApiUrl]];
    sharedManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;    
    [sharedManager setupRequestDescriptor];
    [sharedManager setupResponseDescriptor];
    [sharedManager setupCoreDataWithRKObjectManager:sharedManager];        
    return sharedManager;
}

- (void)setupRequestDescriptor { }    
- (void)setupResponseDescriptor { }

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)setupCoreDataWithRKObjectManager:(RKObjectManager *)manager
{
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
    manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;        
    [managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
    NSString *dbName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.sqlite", kDataBaseName];
    NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];
    NSError *error;
    NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore
                                          addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath
                                          fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil
                                          withConfiguration:nil
                                          options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @YES}
                                          error:&error];
    NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent Store with error - %@", error.localizedDescription);
    [managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
    managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];    
}

@end
```

Then for each entity create inherited class with singleton - `ItemManager`

```
@implementation ItemManager

#pragma mark - Singleton

+ (instancetype)sharedManager
{
    static ItemManager *sharedManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^ {
        sharedManager = [super sharedManager];
    });
    return sharedManager;
}

#pragma mark - Public

- (void)loadItemWithId:(NSInteger)itemId success:(ObjectSuccess)success failure:(ObjectFailure)failure
{
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"item_id" : @(itemId) };
    [self getObjectsAtPath:kItemsDetailsPathPattern parameters:parameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if (success) {
            success(mappingResult.array);
        }
    } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (failure) {
            failure (operation, error);
        }
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (void)setupResponseDescriptor
{
    [super setupResponseDescriptor];
    NSIndexSet *statusCode = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
    RKResponseDescriptor *itemDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor
                                            responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider mappingForItemRKEntity]
                                            method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:kItemsDetailsPathPattern
                                            keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:statusCode];

    [self addResponseDescriptor:itemDescriptor];
}    
@end
```

For mapping I add next class - `MappingProvider`

```
@implementation MappingProvider

#pragma mark - EntityMapping

+ (RKEntityMapping *)mappingForItemRKEntity
{
    RKEntityMapping *itemEntityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:MPItemEntityName inManagedObjectStore:[RKBaseObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

    itemEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"itemID"];
    [itemEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[self mappingDictionaryForItem]];
    return itemEntityMapping;
}

+ (RKObjectMapping *)mappingForItemRK
{
    RKObjectMapping *itemMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ItemRK class]];
    [itemMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[self mappingDictionaryForItem]];

    return itemMapping;
}

#pragma mark - Private

+ (NSDictionary *)mappingDictionaryForItem
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                                 @"item_id" : @"itemID",
                                 @"name" : @"name",
                                 @"description" : @"itemDescription",
                                 @"type" : @"type",
                                 @"level" : @"level",
                                 @"rarity" : @"rarity",
                                 @"vendor_value" : @"vendorValue",
                                 @"icon_file_id" : @"iconFileId",
                                 @"icon_file_signature" : @"iconFileSignature",
                                 @"default_skin" : @"defaultScin"
                                 };
    return dictionary;
}
```

And when I want to get object  -

```
[[ItemManager sharedManager] loadItemWithId:28445 success:^(NSArray *mappingResult) {
    ItemRK *result = (ItemRK *)[mappingResult firstObject];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Fail to load - %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Test entity class (autoGenerated)

```
@interface ItemRK : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * defaultScin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * flags;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * gameTypes;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * iconFileId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * iconFileSignature;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * itemID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * level;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * rarity;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * restrictions;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * vendorValue;
@property (nonatomic, retain) WeaponRK *weapon;

@end
```

So the problem is as I wrote at beggining - something with `core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache`. Also try to found similar problems:

1. [To many unique keys added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17586880/2012219) - not the reason - I use only one `itemEntityMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"itemID"];`
2. [To many request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25818113/2012219) - not the reason - only one request;

API for my example - https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/item_details.json?item_id=28445 - checked with Postman - OK.

So think I was wrong somewhere in mapping and combining it to CoreData - but cant find where.

**Question** - where i make mistake? Why i cant combine RestKit and CoreData?

Comment: Do you still get the error if you reset the simulator? iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents and Settings (menu option)

Comment: @Asciant, yes I try it - nothing help, currently try to code all from scratch...

Comment: Sorry Krill, I am not sure, although I suspect if you comment out this line you may be able to narrow it down. managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

Comment: Have you checked that the managed object contexts are created, any errors raised there? Are your managed object classes automatically generated by Xcode?

Comment: @Wain, hello managed object contexts are created - YES, no errors raised, managedObjectClasses - I generate after creating of DB - automatically.

Comment: @Asciant - found the problem - please see my answer, anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally **found the reason** -

When I create `ItemManager` I also automatically try to add response descriptor (with this method `setupResponseDescriptor`), last use mapping, and mapping use 'BaseObjectManager' as it managedObjectStore the is a parent for `ItemManager`. So during creating `ItemManager` I create infinity cycle - as result program crashed.

Solution - I create response descriptor in class where I call `ItemManager` like

```
[[ItemManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:[ResponseDescriptorProvider itemResponseDescriptor]];
[[ItemManager sharedManager] loadItemWithId:28450 success:^(NSArray *result) {
    NSArray *arout = result;
    NSLog(@"Result: Item -  %@ and nested Weapon - %@", (ItemRK *)[arout firstObject], ((WeaponRK *)((ItemRK *)[arout firstObject]).weapon).type );
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error response': %@", error);
}];
```

Also i moved out response descriptor from manager to separate class - `ResponseDescriptorProvider`

```
+ (RKResponseDescriptor *)itemResponseDescriptor
{
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[MappingProvider mappingForItemRKEntity]
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:kItemsDetailsPathPattern
                                                keyPath:nil
                                            statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    return responseDescriptor;
}
```

The rest leave the same.

Thanks all for help.